# Is a readonly EnumSet iterator thread safe?

Tags: java, collections, thread-safety, enumset

I have an `EnumSet` which is final and immutable i.e. initialized once in the constructor.

Is the `contains()` method on this `EnumSet` thread safe? It is internally using an iterator to make the contains check. Hence if two threads are simultaneously calling the `contains()` can the iterator position in one call effect other one?  Or are the iterators having different instances in these two thread calls?

Answer (score 1):

The *contents* of an `EnumSet` can be changed despite the *reference* to it being final.  No `EnumSet` is immutable.  You can, however, wrap your `EnumSet` via `Collections.unmodifiableSet()`.  If you also avoid retaining any reference to the original `EnumSet` then the unmodifiable wrapper object is functionally immutable.

Mutability notwithstanding, two iterators operating over the same `Set` at the same time presents no problem as long as the `Set` is not modified.  This isn't really any different from the case of just one iterator.

In any case, the `contains()` method of an `EnumSet` likely doesn't create or use an iterator.  The class implements membership via a bit vector, so it uses bit operations to perform the `contains()` test.

Answer (score 0):

No, if two threads call `contains()` at the same time, that will call `iterator()` twice which will create two separate iterators.

If you were trying to share an iterator between two threads, *that* would not be a good idea.

Note that if you modify the set in one thread while iterating over it (e.g. via `contains`) in another, then this bit of the docs comes into play:

> The returned iterator is weakly consistent: it will never throw ConcurrentModificationException and it may or may not show the effects of any modifications to the set that occur while the iteration is in progress.